# Почему не находит библиотеку ? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbs.Driver

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, mysqlconnector

Не находит файл библиотеки хотя она уже загружена.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbs.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at com.example.myapp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.myapp.DataBaseHandler.getDbConnection(DataBaseHandler.java:14)
    at com.example.myapp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.myapp.DataBaseHandler.signUpUser(DataBaseHandler.java:24)
    at com.example.myapp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.myapp.app3Controller.lambda$initialize$3(app3Controller.java:91)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

```
package com.example.myapp;
    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
    
public class DataBaseHandler extends Configs {
    Connection dbConnection;
    
    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;
    
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbs.Driver");
    
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
        return dbConnection;
    }
    
    public void signUpUser(String username, String password) {
        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Const.USER_TABLE + "(" + Const.USERS_NAME + "," + Const.USERS_PASSWORD + ")"
                + "VALUE(?,?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Опечатка. `com.mysql.jdbs.Driver` должно быть `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно проверить, что ссылка на .jar файл с драйвером добавлена в секцию зависимостей в `build.gradle` (судя по скриншоту, этой ссылки нет):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'
}
```

---

Так как конфигурация `compile` из Java плагина устарела, и фактически не поддерживается начиная [с версии Gradle 7.0](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph), следует использовать `implementation` вместо `compile` или `runtimeOnly` вместо `runtime`:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27")
}
```

Comment: Я добавил compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27' в build.gradle
И при загрузке: https://yapx.ru/v/P7WUM

Comment: Скорей всего у вас новая версия gradle :)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает!))))

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема с путями в Class.forName(). Попробуйте посмотреть исходники этого класса, особенно обратите внимание на строчку package в исходном коде (там указан путь к файлу).

Comment: Как оказалось я написал jdbs вместо jdbc, но всё равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Кстати говоря эта строчка же ничего не делает. Просто пытается найти Class и возвращает ссылку на него (возвращаемый Class просто пропадает), вы теряете ссылку и её уничтожает сборщик мусора.

Comment: А как можно добавить jdbc драйвер в classpath?

Comment: Вроде как эта строчка Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  как раз устанавливает какой драйвер я буду использовать.

Comment: Да, этот метод заставляет jvm загрузить этот класс